Assign Custom Taxonomies to a Custom Post When its Created, Dependant on the Options Chosen on the Form
I'm using ACF to generate new custom posts from a form submission made by WP User Frontend.
It's generating the post and populating the fields as intended, but on the form, there are 8 different radio options with 2 values in each, so the user can select the services their business offers.
I need to assign custom taxonomies to the post depending on the values they've chosen in each, as well as have them update if the user edits their options later on.
Here is the code i've tried so far but to no avail:
    // Check if it's a custom post type
    if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'business-user') { // Change 'business-user' to your actual custom post type if different
        return;
    }

    // Define the terms for each radio option and its selections
    $options_terms = array(
        'service_1' => array( // Change 'service_1' to your actual ACF option field name
            'Service One' => 'Service One', // Change 'Service One' to the actual value and term you want
            'No' => 'No', // Change 'No' to the actual value and term you want
        ),
        'service_2' => array( // Change 'service_2' to your actual ACF option field name
            'Service Two' => 'Service Two', // Change 'Service Two' to the actual value and term you want
            'No' => 'No', // Change 'No' to the actual value and term you want
        ),
        // Continue for other option fields
        'service_3' => array(
            'Service Three' => 'Service Three',
            'No' => 'No',
        ),
        'service_4' => array(
            'Service Four' => 'Service Four',
            'No' => 'No',
        ),
        'service_5' => array(
            'Service Five' => 'Service Five',
            'No' => 'No',
        ),
        'service_6' => array(
            'Service Six' => 'Service Six',
            'No' => 'No',
        ),
        'service_7' => array(
            'Service Seven' => 'Service Seven',
            'No' => 'No',
        ),
        'service_8' => array(
            'Service Eight' => 'Service Eight',
            'No' => 'No',
        ),
    );

    $terms_to_assign = array();

    // Iterate through each option field
    foreach ($options_terms as $option_field => $selections) {
        // Get the value of the current option field
        $option_value = get_field($option_field, 'option'); // Ensure 'option' is used for ACF options page fields

        // Check if the option value exists in the selections array
        if (array_key_exists($option_value, $selections)) {
            // Add the corresponding term to the list of terms to assign
            $terms_to_assign[] = $selections[$option_value];
        }
    }

    if (!empty($terms_to_assign)) {
        // Assign the collected terms to the post in the custom taxonomy
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $terms_to_assign, 'service', true); // Change 'your_custom_taxonomy' to your actual custom taxonomy
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'assign_terms_based_on_acf_options');

function update_terms_on_acf_options_change($value, $post_id, $field) {
    // List of your option fields
    $option_fields = array(
        'service_1', // Change these to your actual ACF option field names
        'service_2',
        'service_3',
        'service_4',
        'service_5',
        'service_6',
        'service_7',
        'service_8'
    );

    // Ensure it's one of the option fields
    if (in_array($field['name'], $option_fields)) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'business-user', // Change 'business-user' to your actual custom post type
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            // Update terms for each post
            assign_terms_based_on_acf_options($post->ID);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/update_value', 'update_terms_on_acf_options_change', 10, 3);


Any help greatly appreciated.

Could you please fix the hook to run the taxonomy assignment after the ACF fields are saved. Also please ensure correct values are being retrieved from the ACF fields.
Also please give a try to the given code, it should works for you.
<?php
function assign_terms_based_on_acf_options( $post_id )
{
    // Here we have checked if it's a custom post type.
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'business-user' ) { // Change 'business-user' to your actual custom post type if different
        return;
    }

    // Define the terms for each radio option and its selections
    $options_terms = array(
        'service_1' => array( // Here we are changing 'service_1' to your actual ACF option field name
            'Service One' => 'Service One', // Change 'Service One' to the actual value and term you want
            'No'          => 'No', // Change 'No' to the actual value and term you want
        ),
        'service_2' => array( // Here we are changing 'service_2' to your actual ACF option field name
            'Service Two' => 'Service Two', // Change 'Service Two' to the actual value and term you want
            'No'          => 'No', // Here we are changing 'No' to the actual value and term you want
        ),
        // Continue for other option fields
        'service_3' => array(
            'Service Three' => 'Service Three',
            'No'            => 'No',
        ),
        'service_4' => array(
            'Service Four' => 'Service Four',
            'No'           => 'No',
        ),
        'service_5' => array(
            'Service Five' => 'Service Five',
            'No'           => 'No',
        ),
        'service_6' => array(
            'Service Six' => 'Service Six',
            'No'          => 'No',
        ),
        'service_7' => array(
            'Service Seven' => 'Service Seven',
            'No'            => 'No',
        ),
        'service_8' => array(
            'Service Eight' => 'Service Eight',
            'No'            => 'No',
        ),
    );

    $terms_to_assign = array();

    // Here we are iterating through each option field.
    foreach ( $options_terms as $option_field => $selections ) {
        // Here we are getting the value of the current option field.
        $option_value = get_field($option_field, $post_id);

        // Need to check if the option value exists in the selections array.
        if (array_key_exists($option_value, $selections)) {
            // Here we hae added the corresponding term to the list of terms to assign
            if ( $option_value != 'No' ) {
                $terms_to_assign[] = $selections[ $option_value ];
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($terms_to_assign)) {
        // Here we assign the collected terms to the post in the custom taxonomy.
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $terms_to_assign, 'service', false); // Change 'service' to your actual custom taxonomy as per your need
    }
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'assign_terms_based_on_acf_options', 20);

function update_terms_on_acf_options_change($value, $post_id, $field)
{
    // Here we are listing our option fields.
    $option_fields = array(
        'service_1', // Here we are changing these to actual ACF option field names.
        'service_2',
        'service_3',
        'service_4',
        'service_5',
        'service_6',
        'service_7',
        'service_8'
    );

    // Ensure it's one of the option fields
    if ( in_array( $field['name'], $option_fields, true ) ) {
        // Here we are updating terms for current post.
        assign_terms_based_on_acf_options( $post_id );
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'acf/update_value', 'update_terms_on_acf_options_change', 10, 3 );


Unfortunately this isn't working either, but I appreciate the response.
